# Pytorch tensor to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I have a pytorch `Tensor` of shape `[4, 3, 966, 1296]`. I want to convert it to `numpy` array using the following code:

```
imgs = imgs.numpy()[:, ::-1, :, :]
```

How does that code work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: your question is extremely confusing. You already have a `.numpy()` call. What exactly are you confused about? Do you not understand slicing notation in python or what?

Comment: btw you might need to call `.detach()` before saving your data e.g. `x.detach().numpy()` if your tensors have grads...also you might need to call `cpu()`. I think this should work: `x.detach().cpu().numpy()`

Comment: When converting to numpy you should call detach before cpu to prevent superfluous gradient copying. See https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/should-it-really-be-necessary-to-do-var-detach-cpu-numpy/35489/5

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There are 4 dimensions of the tensor you want to convert.

```
[:, ::-1, :, :]
```

`:` means that the first dimension should be copied as it is and converted, same goes for the third and fourth dimension.

`::-1` means that for the second axes it reverses the the axes

Comment: Are you certain? To me it looks more like axes `0,2,3` are copied as-is, and axis `1` is reversed.

Comment: Real answer: `x.detach().cpu().numpy()`

Comment: When converting to numpy you should call detach before cpu to prevent superfluous gradient copying. See https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/should-it-really-be-necessary-to-do-var-detach-cpu-numpy/35489/5

Comment: `x.detach().cpu().numpy()` works for me~!

Answer (score 147):

I believe you also have to use `.detach()`. I had to convert my Tensor to a numpy array on Colab which uses CUDA and GPU. I did it like the following:

```
# this is just my embedding matrix which is a Torch tensor object
embedding = learn.model.u_weight

embedding_list = list(range(0, 64382))

input = torch.cuda.LongTensor(embedding_list)
tensor_array = embedding(input)
# the output of the line below is a numpy array
tensor_array.cpu().detach().numpy()
```

Comment: Of course you had to use `detach` because you originally created a PyTorch Tensor on the GPU.  That doesn't apply if it's created in CPU, as seen in the original post.

Comment: I think that even if your tensor is in the CPU, if you want a `raw` tensor, you have to `.detach()`.

Comment: When converting to `numpy` you should call `detach` before `cpu` to prevent superfluous gradient copying.  See https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/should-it-really-be-necessary-to-do-var-detach-cpu-numpy/35489/5

Answer (score 60):

This worked for me:

```
np_arr = torch_tensor.detach().cpu().numpy()
```

Comment: I think there is a difference in the order perhaps this is better? `x.detach().cpu().numpy()`

Comment: What is the use of cpu() here?

Answer (score 29):

While other answers **perfectly**  explained the question I will add some real life examples converting tensors to numpy array:

#### Example: **Shared storage**

PyTorch tensor residing on CPU shares the same storage as numpy array `na`

```
import torch
a = torch.ones((1,2))
print(a)
na = a.numpy()
na[0][0]=10
print(na)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[1., 1.]])
[[10.  1.]]
tensor([[10.,  1.]])
```

#### Example: **Eliminate effect of shared storage, copy numpy array first**

To avoid the effect of shared storage we need to `copy()` the numpy array `na` to a new numpy array `nac`. Numpy `copy()` method creates the new separate storage.

```py
import torch
a = torch.ones((1,2))
print(a)
na = a.numpy()
nac = na.copy()
nac[0][0]=10
​print(nac)
print(na)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[1., 1.]])
[[10.  1.]]
[[1. 1.]]
tensor([[1., 1.]])
```

Now, just the `nac` numpy array will be altered with the line `nac[0][0]=10`, `na` and `a` will remain as is.

#### Example: **CPU tensor with `requires_grad=True`**

```py
import torch
a = torch.ones((1,2), requires_grad=True)
print(a)
na = a.detach().numpy()
na[0][0]=10
print(na)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[1., 1.]], requires_grad=True)
[[10.  1.]]
tensor([[10.,  1.]], requires_grad=True)
```

In here we call:

```py
na = a.numpy()
```

This would cause: `RuntimeError: Can't call numpy() on Tensor that requires grad. Use tensor.detach().numpy() instead.`, because tensors that `require_grad=True` are recorded by PyTorch AD. Note that `tensor.detach()` is the new way for `tensor.data`.

This explains why we need to `detach()` them first before converting using `numpy()`.

#### Example: **CUDA tensor with `requires_grad=False`**

```py
a = torch.ones((1,2), device='cuda')
print(a)
na = a.to('cpu').numpy()
na[0][0]=10
print(na)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[1., 1.]], device='cuda:0')
[[10.  1.]]
tensor([[1., 1.]], device='cuda:0')
```

​

#### Example: **CUDA tensor with `requires_grad=True`**

```py
a = torch.ones((1,2), device='cuda', requires_grad=True)
print(a)
na = a.detach().to('cpu').numpy()
na[0][0]=10
​print(na)
print(a)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[1., 1.]], device='cuda:0', requires_grad=True)
[[10.  1.]]
tensor([[1., 1.]], device='cuda:0', requires_grad=True)
```

Without `detach()` method the error `RuntimeError: Can't call` numpy() `on Tensor that requires grad. Use tensor.detach().numpy() instead.` will be set.

Without `.to('cpu')` method `TypeError: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.` will be set.

You could use `cpu()` but instead of `to('cpu')` but I prefer the newer `to('cpu')`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this syntax if some grads are attached with your variables.

`y=torch.Tensor.cpu(x).detach().numpy()[:,:,:,-1]`

Comment: This doesn't contribute to this question any more than the other answers here.

Comment: What is with the x in the cpu call?

Comment: Are you sure you need the `.cpu()` call?

Comment: When converting to numpy you should call detach before cpu to prevent superfluous gradient copying. See https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/should-it-really-be-necessary-to-do-var-detach-cpu-numpy/35489/5

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very poorly worded. Your code (sort of) already does what you want. What exactly are you confused about? `x.numpy()` answer the original title of your question:

> Pytorch tensor to numpy array

you need improve your question starting with your title.

Anyway, just in case this is useful to others. You might need to call detach for your code to work. e.g.

```
RuntimeError: Can't call numpy() on Variable that requires grad.
```

So call `.detach()`. Sample code:

```
# creating data and running through a nn and saving it

import torch
import torch.nn as nn

from pathlib import Path
from collections import OrderedDict

import numpy as np

path = Path('~/data/tmp/').expanduser()
path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

num_samples = 3
Din, Dout = 1, 1
lb, ub = -1, 1

x = torch.torch.distributions.Uniform(low=lb, high=ub).sample((num_samples, Din))

f = nn.Sequential(OrderedDict([
    ('f1', nn.Linear(Din,Dout)),
    ('out', nn.SELU())
]))
y = f(x)

# save data
y.numpy()
x_np, y_np = x.detach().cpu().numpy(), y.detach().cpu().numpy()
np.savez(path / 'db', x=x_np, y=y_np)

print(x_np)
```

cpu goes after detach. See: https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/should-it-really-be-necessary-to-do-var-detach-cpu-numpy/35489/5

---

Also I won't make any comments on the slicking since that is off topic and that should not be the focus of your question. See this:

[Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)