# Add tensor to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor with the following characteristics:

```
<class 'torch.Tensor'>

torch.Size([600, 1])
```

I would like it to be a column in a data frame.

When I add the tensor to a df as is, I get the following for one of the rows.

```
tensor([-0.1186])
```

How do I get rid of the `tensor([])`? So that each row is just a number. For this row, I would just want `-0.1186`.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768306/pytorch-tensor-to-numpy-array

Answer (score 0):

If you `squeeze` your tensor from size `(600,1)` to size `(600)` you can directly add its values as a new column to a DataFrame:

```
df['newcol'] = my_tensor.squeeze()
```